# Rails how to encapsulate 2 var inside a argument?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This seems a trivial question but, after setup a simple standart rails method, i'd like to pass more than one param to a argument here is de code below:

```
 def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params)

    @comment.user = current_user

    Notification.create!(action: "posted", actor: current_user,
      recipient: ([@post.user, @comment.user]), notifiable: @comment)


    if @comment.save

      render json: "Commented successfully", status: 201
    else
      render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

if the recipient just receive @post.user is OK but, i'd like to know if is possible to pass @comment.user or any other var inside this kind of statement

Comment: When a method expects one argument then Ruby doesn't care if you pass one instance of a user or one array. But the method must be able to deal with both when you want to be able to pass a single instance or an array. Therefore the answer if this is possible in your example depends on the receiver. What is `Notification.create!`? How does that method look like?

Comment: @spickermann, thank you for your interest. but still a bit confusing.

the the receiver is just belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User' on notification model

Comment: I understand. I didn't know that `Notification` is a ordinary ActiveRecord model with a  `belongs_to :recipient`. Than the answer is that this will only work if you change to whole association from a `belongs_to :recipient` to a `has_and_belongs_to_many :recipients`. And that will require a change in the database structure too. I suggest to read: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Passing in an array to an argument is a perfectly valid way of doing it and doesn't require the surrounding parentheses. `recipient: [ a, b ]` works just fine.

Comment: spickermann the recipient is a attr of Notification 

so Notification is a polymorphic model.

@tadman thank you i've tried to pass a array but in the logs shows a missMach

 ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#47328244232180) expected, got

Comment: Oh, I mistook this for an email notifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a proper `has_many` type relationship, then you can do this:

```
Notification.create!(action: "posted", actor: current_user,
  recipients: [ @post.user, @comment.user ], notifiable: @comment)
)
```

Where you just pass those in. If you don't have a many-to-many association between Notification and User then you need to create multiple records:

```
[ @post.user, @comment.user ].each do |user|
  Notification.create!(action: "posted", actor: current_user,
    recipient: user, notifiable: @comment)
  )
end
```

The first approach is preferred but requires a proper join table between User and Notification.

Comment: Tadman, thank you man!

ok, so istead of encapsulate i can pass the instances as arrays